# Create a new menu item in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is it possible to create a new menu item in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

For example when you right-click the a database a list of options appears (New Database, New Query ... ).

Is it possible to add a new item in that list and implement some C# functionality when clicking that button?

Comment: Here is project on codeplex that helps you develop addins for Sql Server Management Studio:
http://ssmsaddins.codeplex.com/ It's probably not allow to straight extend context menu but it's good start point.

Comment: Probably ask the same question in MSDN forum as well and see if anyone have done something before. To my knowledge, that option is not available.

Comment: Take a look at this proposed enhancement which has marked as won't fix for now. http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/376344/add-new-context-menu-item-to-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: SQL Server is a database management system - it doesn't have any menus you can extend. Are you talking about the SQL Server **Management Studio** ??

Comment: yes.. sql server management studio

Comment: Definitely possible. The SSMS Tools Pack addin does this. It allows you to add in custom new items but TSQL only IIRC

Comment: http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174178%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Adding a New Item to the Menu
To add a new item to the menu

> 1. On the Tools menu, click Options.
> 2. In the Customize dialog box, on the Commands tab, click New Menu.
> 3. On the Commands box, drag New Menu to the menu bar and drop it where you want the new menu to appear.
> 4. On the menu, right-click New Menu, and in the Name box, type a name for the new menu.
> 5. In the Customize dialog box, select category such as File, and select a command such as Open File. Drag the command to the new menu. As you point to the new menu, the menu will expand. Drop the command onto the expanded menu.
> 6. In the Customize dialog box, click Close.

Comment: It might just be a difference in versions but, in step 1 above, using SSMS v18, you want to click the Tools menu and then click the Customize command, not Options.